# Can we train a single model for multiple type of forms?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am using Microsoft form-recognizer cognitive service to train a model for forms. My question is that can we train a single model for multiple type of forms? Is it recommended? I have many multiple types of forms and I choose to train a single model for four different types, it get trained but is it a recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

This has been given as an answer to the question by Microsoft Cognitive Services Admin:

"Form Recognizer supports training a single model for different types of forms. The model quality should be the same for a single type model and a multi type model per type."